# No se activan los eventos en un llamado a ajax en success

Tags: jquery, ajax

Como dice en el titulo tengo un llamado ajax que en conjunto lo uso con el jquery validator, el problema es cuando utilizo la funcion que viene con el validator que se llama isDefaultPrevented()  la validacion funciona a la perfeccion sin problemas excepto que no se activa nada dentro del success del ajax, dentro de ahi tengo que llama a un modal y tambien ni siquiera se dispara el console log, si quito el isDefaultPrevented() y solo uso el preventDefault, hace trigger a la verificacion del formulario y detecta los errores pero realiza el llamado ajax y ahi si funcionan bien los modales.  Habra alguna otra alternativa? Muchas Gracias.

```
$('#candidateForm').validator().on('submit', function(e) {
    if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        // handle the invalid form...
    } else {
        var dataString = $('#candidateForm').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "work/php/onlineApplication/addNewCandidate.php",
            data: dataString,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(result['data'].status);
                if (result['data'].status == 'error') {
                    $("#bodyMsgModal").html(result['data'].message);
                    $("#addUserModal").modal('show');
                    $(result['data'].Field).focus();
                }
                if (result['data'].status == 'success') {
                    $("#bodyMsgModalSuccess").html(result['data'].message);
                    $("#addUserModalSuccess").modal('show');
                    $('#candidateForm')[0].reset();
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: ya encontre la solución! gracias de antemano

Comment: Puedes publicar tu respuesta para que sepamos como lo solucionaste!

Comment: Claro que si, suena algo tonto pero solo le puse e.preventDefault() enseguida del else.

Comment: creo que no debías usar la condición if sino que sólo colocas el e.preventDefault() antes de enviar el ajax

Comment: tambien lo puse de esa forma y no funciono eso me impedia por completo el llamado ajax

Answer (score 1):

Esta es la parte de mi solucion asi me funciona

```
$('#candidateForm').validator().on('submit', function(e) {
    if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        // handle the invalid form...
    } else {
      e.preventDefault();
        var dataString = $('#candidateForm').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "work/php/onlineApplication/addNewCandidate.php",
            data: dataString,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(result['data'].status);
                if (result['data'].status == 'error') {
                    $("#bodyMsgModal").html(result['data'].message);
                    $("#addUserModal").modal('show');
                    $(result['data'].Field).focus();
                }
                if (result['data'].status == 'success') {
                    $("#bodyMsgModalSuccess").html(result['data'].message);
                    $("#addUserModalSuccess").modal('show');
                    $('#candidateForm')[0].reset();
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Y si intentas no hacer un evento submit, sino un `onclick()`?, es decir, al botón que usas para enviar el formulario le pones un id y cambias el tipo de submit a button, no sé como tengas la estructura HTML pero debe funcionar:

Ejemplo

```
//Aquí el boton
<button type="button" name="enviar" id="enviar">Enviar</button>


$('#enviar').validator().on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
        var dataString = $('#candidateForm').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "work/php/onlineApplication/addNewCandidate.php",
            data: dataString,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(result['data'].status);
                if (result['data'].status == 'error') {
                    $("#bodyMsgModal").html(result['data'].message);
                    $("#addUserModal").modal('show');
                    $(result['data'].Field).focus();
                }
                if (result['data'].status == 'success') {
                    $("#bodyMsgModalSuccess").html(result['data'].message);
                    $("#addUserModalSuccess").modal('show');
                    $('#candidateForm')[0].reset();
                }
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: de hecho asi lo tenia, pero al momento de dar el submit si marcaba la validacion y de igual manera dispara el llamado ajax y pues me hace un insert que no quiero.

Comment: He editado la respuesta, intenta de esa manera, quizás funcione

Comment: a ver deja intento

Comment: no funciono de hecho si salen los modales pero no valida

Comment: quizás podrías mostrarnos mas código de que como validas, porque la respuesta que doy es en base quizás a suposiciones o sino publica otra respuesta con lo que hiciste para solucionarlos